# Array of LinkedLists

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, hashtable

I've been trying to implement a hash table in Java for an exercise. For that, I'm trying to use an array of linked lists. Following is a part of the code:

```
class HashSet implements HashInterface {

    private final int TABLE_SIZE = 100;
    private LinkedList<Integer>[] myTable;

    myTable = (LinkedList<Integer>[]) new LinkedList[TABLE_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
        myTable[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>;
}
```

The problem is, whenever I run the code, it says:

```
C:\Java\hash>javac Main.java
Main.java:17: error: <identifier> expected
    myTable = (LinkedList<Integer>[]) new LinkedList[TABLE_SIZE];
           ^
Main.java:19: error: illegal start of type
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    ^
Main.java:19: error: ')' expected
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
              ^
Main.java:19: error: illegal start of type
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                 ^
Main.java:19: error: <identifier> expected
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                  ^
Main.java:19: error: ';' expected
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                   ^
Main.java:19: error: > expected
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                                  ^
Main.java:19: error: '(' expected
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                                     ^
Main.java:20: error: ']' expected
        myTable[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>;
                ^
Main.java:20: error: ';' expected
        myTable[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>;
                 ^
Main.java:20: error: <identifier> expected
        myTable[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>;
                                            ^
11 errors
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You should also consider an IDE while starting out (if it is a possibility). Java lends itself nicely to markup and Netbeans or Eclipse both have code completion/syntax highlighting which will help you learn the language. Also, its a very verbose language so an IDE is basically mandatory for productivity. The above "code outside" a method would have had a wonderful red squiggly.

Comment: I'm actually fairly anti-IDE when starting out. They add a level of complexity and hide the underpinnings of the Java compilation and execution environments. They're easier to learn when they must be explicitly stated and understood, and make future IDE work quite a bit easier. YMMV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've put code outside a method (and outside static initialization blocks).

You can declare variables, but not execute code. The bulk of your code should be in methods.

Answer (score 1):

Change this -

```
myTable[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>;
```

to

```
myTable[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Also as @Dav Newton mentioned - Your processing code should be inside a method.